# iPhone: Make UIScrollView from UIView

Tags: iphone, uiview, uiscrollview, scroll

I have a **UIView** with labels and textfields and I tested it in the simulator and noticed that I cannot scroll to see the rest of the view, how can I make the view into a **UIScrollView** and what do I need to do so I can make the view scrollable? I don't want to move labels and stuff or delete the **UIView**, is there a simple way?

Comment: Is it the root view of the view controller?  If so, I don't think there's an alternative:  select all the subviews, cut, drag in a scroll view, select it, paste.  Unfortunately this will more than likely do away with all the framing you provided those subviews.

Answer (score 1):

Take a `UIScrollView` in `Xib` file outside your view. drag your view into this `scrollview`. The `subviews` inside your view remains same. and set the `scrollview`'s `contentSize`